# How to map a vec into hashmap without having to use as many as_ref and clone?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

So let's say I have these structs:

```
    struct Data {
        url: String,
        timestamp: u32
    }
    struct AuthorAndData {
        url: String,
        timestamp: u32,
        author: String
    }
```

and I want to transform a vec of `Data` into a hash map where `AuthorAndData` is the value.

Basically given this:

```
    let input: Vec<(Result<Data, String>, String)> = vec![(Ok(Data {
        url: "http://google.com".to_string(),
        timestamp: 1234566,
    }), "john".to_string()), (Ok(Data {
        url: "http://yahoo.com".to_string(),
        timestamp: 2333333,
    }), "doe".to_string()), (Ok(Data {
        url: "http://google.com".to_string(),
        timestamp: 2333353,
    }), "doe".to_string())];
```

I want to turn it into a hash map, where the URL is the key, and the value is a vec of `AuthorAndData`.

Basically go from `Vec<(Result<Data, String>, String)>` -> `HashMap<String, Vec<AuthorAndData>>`

My first attempt was this:

```
    let mut mappped: HashMap<String, Vec<AuthorAndData>> = HashMap::new();

    input.iter().for_each(|entry| {
        mappped.entry(entry.0.unwrap().url).and_modify(|value| value.push(AuthorAndData {
            url: entry.0.unwrap().url,
            timestamp: entry.0.unwrap().timestamp,
            author: entry.1
        })).or_insert(vec![AuthorAndData {
            url: entry.0.unwrap().url,
            timestamp: entry.0.unwrap().timestamp,
            author: entry.1
        }]);
    });
```

But this fail compilation with the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `entry.0` which is behind a shared reference
    --> src/main.rs:60:18
     |
60   |             url: entry.0.unwrap().url,
     |                  ^^^^^^^ -------- `entry.0` moved due to this method call
     |                  |
     |                  help: consider calling `.as_ref()` or `.as_mut()` to borrow the type's contents
     |                  move occurs because `entry.0` has type `Result<Data, std::string::String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
     |
```

After fixing these error by adding `.as_ref()` I had a couple more errors that involved adding `clone()`. For example this version:

```
    let mut mappped: HashMap<String, Vec<AuthorAndData>> = HashMap::new();

    input.iter().for_each(|entry| {
        mappped.entry(entry.0.as_ref().unwrap().url).and_modify(|value| value.push(AuthorAndData {
            url: entry.0.as_ref().unwrap().url,
            timestamp: entry.0.unwrap().timestamp,
            author: entry.1
        })).or_insert(vec![AuthorAndData {
            url: entry.0.unwrap().url,
            timestamp: entry.0.unwrap().timestamp,
            author: entry.1
        }]);
    });
```

failed with

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:60:18
   |
60 |             url: entry.0.as_ref().unwrap().url,
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

but appending `clone()` ie having the line as `entry.0.as_ref().unwrap().url.clone()` fixed it.

The final version that did what I wanted is reproduced below:

```
fn main() {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Data {
        url: String,
        timestamp: u32
    }
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct AuthorAndData {
        url: String,
        timestamp: u32,
        author: String
    }

    let input: Vec<(Result<Data, String>, String)> = vec![(Ok(Data {
        url: "http://google.com".to_string(),
        timestamp: 1234566,
    }), "john".to_string()), (Ok(Data {
        url: "http://yahoo.com".to_string(),
        timestamp: 2333333,
    }), "doe".to_string()), (Ok(Data {
        url: "http://google.com".to_string(),
        timestamp: 2333353,
    }), "doe".to_string())];

    let mut mappped: HashMap<String, Vec<AuthorAndData>> = HashMap::new();

    input.iter().for_each(|entry| {
        mappped.entry(entry.0.as_ref().unwrap().url.clone()).and_modify(|value| value.push(AuthorAndData {
            url: entry.0.as_ref().unwrap().url.clone(),
            timestamp: entry.0.as_ref().unwrap().timestamp.clone(),
            author: entry.1.clone()
        })).or_insert(vec![AuthorAndData {
            url: entry.0.as_ref().unwrap().url.clone(),
            timestamp: entry.0.as_ref().unwrap().timestamp.clone(),
            author: entry.1.clone()
        }]);
    });

    dbg!(mappped);
}
```

Running this prints the right results but I have doubts if this is the best approach giving all the `as_ref` and `clone` I had to sprinkle across the place to get this working.

Anyone knows:

1. Why the need for all the `as_ref` and `clone`
2. A better approach that won't need all these `as_ref` and `clone`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why the need for all the `as_ref` and `clone`

Because you only have a shared reference from `iter()`, you cannot move out of it. `unwrap()` moves out of the `Option`, so you need `as_ref()`. Moving the fields is also not possible, so you need `clone()`.

> 2. A better approach that won't need all these `as_ref` and `clone`

If you'll change `iter()` to `into_iter()`, you can change the `or_insert()` to move the value (and also, prefer `or_insert_with()` in order to not allocate the vector when the entry is already full):

```rust
.or_insert_with(|| {
    let entry_0 = entry.0.unwrap();
    vec![AuthorAndData {
        url: entry_0.url,
        timestamp: entry_0.timestamp,
        author: entry.1,
    }]
});
```

If you will further change the `and_modify().or_insert()` into a `match`, proving to the borrow checker that only one of the branches can ever execute, you can avoid cloning in both:

```rust
input.into_iter().for_each(|entry| {
    match mappped.entry(entry.0.as_ref().unwrap().url.clone()) {
        std::collections::hash_map::Entry::Occupied(mut map_entry) => {
            let entry_0 = entry.0.unwrap();
            map_entry.get_mut().push(AuthorAndData {
                url: entry_0.url,
                timestamp: entry_0.timestamp,
                author: entry.1,
            })
        }
        std::collections::hash_map::Entry::Vacant(map_entry) => {
            let entry_0 = entry.0.unwrap();
            map_entry.insert(vec![AuthorAndData {
                url: entry_0.url,
                timestamp: entry_0.timestamp,
                author: entry.1,
            }]);
        }
    }
});
```

Even better, you can `or_insert()` before the modify for the existing entry, simplifying the code considerably:

```rust
input.into_iter().for_each(|entry| {
    mappped
        .entry(entry.0.as_ref().unwrap().url.clone())
        .or_default()
        .push({
            let entry_0 = entry.0.unwrap();
            AuthorAndData {
                url: entry_0.url,
                timestamp: entry_0.timestamp,
                author: entry.1,
            }
        })
});
```

Comment: you mean `or_default` in your last sentence?

Comment: @FinlayWeber It doesn't matter: `or_insert()` refers to what was previously `or_insert()`, `or_default()` is what it is now.